# add test cases failure reason in extent report

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using

```
selenium webdriver java
```

and in my

```
extent report,
```

i want to add the test cases total failure log.
  How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the test case failure reason, i used the following code:

```
logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, result.getThrowable());
```

where logger is

```
ExtentTest logger
```

and result is

```
ITestResult result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use poi jar files to include excel sheet within selenium script.
Using excel sheet you can report bugs and gathered data in particular format.
and same file can be used for emailing purpose.