# How to print the selenium exception stack trace in Extent reports

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, report

I would like log comments after each step in a Selenium test in Extent reports. Therefore, when an exception thrown in a step, I would like to capture the stack trace and print it out on the Extent Reports. I could not find any help on line. Has anyone tried this before and found a way?

For example, the below create an instance of the report and log the comment

```
// new instance

ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports(file-path, replaceExisting);

// starting test

ExtentTest test = extent.startTest("Test Name", "Sample description");

// step log

test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Click on the object");

Reference:
```

http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/version2/docs.html#initialize-report

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354296/add-test-cases-failure-reason-in-extent-report/34355880#34355880 may be you can find your solution in this link.

Comment: @noor Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to log the stack trace of the exception you can convert the Exception stack trace to String. This class is available in [Apache commons-lang-3.3.4 jar](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) `ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)`

**Simple Example**

```
    try{
             int num[]={1,2,3,4};
             System.out.println(num[5]);
        }catch(Exception e){        
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO/ERROR, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
        }
```

Hope this Helps you...Kindly get back if you have any queries

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply do

```
catch (Exception e) {
    test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ExceptionUtils is deprecated

```
test.log(LogStatus.INFO/ERROR, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace()); ->this won't help
```

So we can use

```
test.log(Status.INFO, "StackTrace Result: " + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExtentReport
{
   public static ExtentReports extentReports;
   public static ExtentTest exParentTest;
   public static ExtentTest exChildTest;
   public static string dirpath;
   public TestContext instance;
   public TestContext TestContext
   {
       set { instance = value; }
       get { return instance; }
   }
   public static void LogReport(string testcase)
   {
       extentReports = new ExtentReports();
       //dirpath = @"..\..\TestExecutionReports\" + '_' + testcase;
       dirpath = @"C:\ExtentReports\" + '_' + testcase;
       ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(dirpath);
       htmlReporter.Config.Theme = Theme.Standard;
       extentReports.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).